# Webpack 4 ts-loader and less-loader not working on certain pc's

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, less

I migrated from webpack 1.x to 4.30. 
node version : 10.15.3
typescript version : 3.4.5
npm version : 6.9.0

This setup works on 3 (windows) pc's but not on one particular machine, although they all use the same versions of node, webpack, npm, other npm packages.

On the not working machine it is as if Webpack does not use the less-loader and ts-loader defined in the webpack.config.ts..  and gives for example the following errors:

`*.less` files beginning with id selector

```
Unexpected character '#' (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
```

`*.less` files beginning with @import

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
```

`*.ts` file (angular component) containing @Component

```
Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
```

I already tried reinstalling node.js, clear npm cache, clear node_modules folder and  new npm install, reboot pc several times..
On another pc where we had the same problem but it was "magically"  solved after a reboot..

webpack.config loaders/rules section

```
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, "Assets")],
        use: [
          "ng-annotate-loader",
          "ts-loader",
          "angular-router-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, "Assets/StyleSheets"), resolve(__dirname, "Assets/NgComponentsNew"), resolve(__dirname, "Assets/WpBundles")],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')({
                'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
              })],
            }
          },
          "less-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, "Assets/NgComponents"), resolve(__dirname, "Assets/NgComponentsNew")],
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, "Assets/Images")],
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "Images/[name].[ext]"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, "Assets/Images"), resolve(__dirname, "Assets/Kendo")],
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "Images/[name].[ext]",
            publicPath: "/mvc/static/"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        include: [resolve(__dirname, "Assets"), resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts"), resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/bootstrap/fonts")],
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "Fonts/[name].[ext]",
            publicPath: "/mvc/static/"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /jquery.+\.js$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'jQuery'
        }, {
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: '$'
        }]
      },
      //avoid "import" warning
      { 
        test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\].+\.js$/, 
        parser: { system: true } 
      }
    ]
  },
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ourproject",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Client Npm Packages",
  "main": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/upgrade": "7.2.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.6.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "4.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "1.4.0",
    "angular": "1.7.8",
    "angular-animate": "1.7.8",
    "angular-filter": "0.5.17",
    "angular-resource": "1.7.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.7.8",
    "angular-translate": "2.18.1",
    "automapper-ts": "1.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-less": "3.3.8",
    "core-js": "3.0.0",
    "eruda": "1.5.0",
    "es5-shim": "4.5.10",
    "golden-layout": "1.5.8",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui-bundle": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.10",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "linq": "3.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26",
    "core.js": "0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.13",
    "@types/angular": "1.6.48",
    "@types/angular-resource": "1.5.14",
    "@types/angular-sanitize": "1.3.7",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.39",
    "@types/core-js": "2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.12",
    "@types/jquery.validation": "1.16.4",
    "@types/kendo-ui": "2018.1.2",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.110",
    "@types/webpack": "4.4.27",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "3.1.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.9",
    "@types/node": "11.13.7",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.5",
    "autoprefixer": "9.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jasmine": "3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.2",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.1",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "0.1.5",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
    "less": "3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "0.6.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "script-loader": "0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "8.0.3",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "util": "0.11.1",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2",
    "webpack-stats-plugin": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2"
  }
```

I would expect that on every machine with the same node.js and the same npm webpack would handle the files correctly

Is there something else that could influence Webpack so loaders are not used/recognized ?

I repeat, this config works without any problem on other pc's..

Any help would be much apreciated..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? (Or more poetically, [Who are you DenverCoder9? What did you see?!](https://xkcd.com/979/))

Comment: @c32hedge no never did figure it out...  the pc in question got replaced and everything worked like it should...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that we had restructured our repo to have a single, root-level `package.json` file instead of one in each of several subdirectories. This meant that unless everyone deleted the old `node_modules` folders, webpack would find one of the stale folders and look there for `ts-loader` instead of looking in the right place.

This can be avoided by telling webpack exactly where to look for loaders using the [resolveLoader](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) configuration option. For example:

```js
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules')],
    mainFields: ['ts-loader']
  },
```

Note that the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) for `resolve.modules`, which also applies to `resolveLoader.modules`, states:

> Absolute and relative paths can both be used, but be aware that they will behave a bit differently.
>
> A relative path will be scanned similarly to how Node scans for
>   node_modules, by looking through the current directory as well as its
>   ancestors (i.e. ./node_modules, ../node_modules, and on).
>
> With an absolute path, it will only search in the given directory.

The default behavior seems to correspond to the relative path approach--any `node_modules` folder in the directory tree between your webpack config file and the folder containing the `node_modules` folder you *expect* to be used will be used instead, and in our case this caused the exact issue you describe as soon as we tried to update TypeScript.

Comment: Solution does not really apply to my situation as I was using only one package.json, and one node_modules folder.

Comment: Interesting. Well, hopefully it will help the next person who stumbles across a similar problem :)